# PnP Core GraphFirst approach

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, pnp-core-sdk

I'm considering about using PnP Core instead of PnP Framework because of using MS Graph API.
But when I setup my project and tried to get list by id app sends request to `/_api/web/lists?$filter=Id+eq+(...)&top=1` instead of using ms graph API request, even if `context.GraphFirst = true`.

The same situation with getting by title: `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('T`, and getting list columns `/_api/Web/Lists(guid'_______')/Fields?$top=100`.

My code:

```
var list = await _context.Web.Lists.GetByTitleAsync(listTitle, p => p.Title, p => p.Id, p=>p.Fields);

var list2 = await _context.Web.Lists.GetByIdAsync(list.Id);
```

I double-checked the setup of the GraphFirst property. But still don't understand why PnP Core still uses these REST API endpoints instead of MS Graph API.
Please explain my this behaviour.